# Ext.Button handler config option

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
    someClass = Ext.extend(someClassB, {
        _someFunctionC{  
           someButton = new Ext.button({  
              handler: function () {
                            this._onClick('click');
                       }
           }),
           _onClick(someMessage){
               Ext.Msg.alert(someMessage);
            }
        }
    }
```

_onClick eats one parameter; in the above code you put in the 'click' event because you want _onClick to be executed after the user clicks on the button. However, how do you specify this specific 'click' registration AND pass in a local variable as the _onClick parameter at the same time?

As an aside, why do you even have to specify 'click', when the API states that handler always pertains to a click? Is this additional information not unnecessary?

Comment: Can you perhaps elaborate a little further? Maybe post some "meta code" that illustrates what you are trying to achieve? It's a little unclear what you are trying to do or what goes wrong

Comment: Does this help? Basically I want to pass in some message.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you set it up like this. No real need to pass parameters since someFunction is a member of your 'class' and has access to any data you'd want.

```
var button = new Ext.Button({
    handler: this.someFunction
    scope: this
});

someFunction: function() {
   // do something interesting.
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. However, this requires some modification on the generated variable that you want to pass in. I'm looking at modifying the handler config option more than circumventing it differently with scope:this. More generally, I try to understand the difference between specifying anonymous function versus specifying the function as suggested by you.

Answer (score 1):

So if i understand correctly you want to set the handler config option but set the arguments yourself in one go?

Does this do what you want?

```
// clicking the button alerts 'Hello World'
new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Test',
    handler: function(value){
        alert('Hello, ' + value);
    }.createCallback('World')
});
```

Notice the `createCallback` executed on the anonymous function, this creates a callback function for `handler` which only gets passed the arguments you pass to `createCallback`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that I've found to do this is to pass a custom config option along with your button. Say you wanted to have a `splitbutton` that could choose the amount of banners to add. (this is from a recent project)

```
{
xtype: 'splitbutton',
iconCls: 'icon addBanners',
ref: '../addBanner',
text: 'Add Banner',
menu: new Ext.menu.Menu({
    items: [{ 
        text: 'Add 10 Banners',
        scope: this,
        handler: this.addBanner,
        numBanners: 10
    },{
        text: 'Add 20 Banners',
        scope: this, 
        handler: this.addBanner,
        numBanners: 20
    }]
}),                    
scope: this,
handler: this.addBanner,
numBanners: 1
}
```

And in your function:

```
addBanner: function(button, event) {
      if (button.numBanners) {
          // do whatever 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a callback function that inserts extra parameters when it is called:

```
var button = new Ext.Button({
    handler: this.someFunction.createDelegate(button,['Some message'])
});
```